# Remove the empty string in the result of `split("");`

Tags: java, split

I want a `String[]` that shows this:

Value1: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`

But when I use `String[] b1 = sByte.split("");`, I get

Value1: `[, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`

That extra position isn't supposed to be there. Is there any way to remove it?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: what is the content of `sByte`

Comment: @njzk2 probably a set of bits saved as string, something like `"00000001"`

Comment: [here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22718096/1113392)

Comment: Do you really need to do it with do it with regex? Why not just use `sByte.toCharArray()` and get a `char[]` as result, if those are supposed to be bit values, this would be more handy to work with (comparison with 0 and 1 using == operator)...

Answer (score 0):

You can split it on a location that is both preceded by and followed by any character:

```
String[] b1 = sByte.split("(?<=[\\s\\S])(?=[\\s\\S])");
```