# Minimum cyclic (forward or backward) shifts to be performed to the string to make it a palindrome

Tags: java, palindrome, cyclic

Below is the problem statement and Solution. Two test cases failed for me. Help me figure it out.

A string is said to be palindrome, if it reads the same from both the ends. Given a string `S`, you are allowed to perform cyclic shifts. More formally, you can pick any one character from any end (head or tail) and you can append that character at the other end. For example, if the string is `"abc"`, then if we do a shift using the character at head position then the string becomes `"bca"`. Similarly, if we do the shift using the character at the tail then the input string becomes `"cab"`. Your task is to find out the minimum number of shifts needed to make the given string, a palindrome. In case, we can't convert the string to palindrome then print `-1`.

Input Format: 
 First line starts with `T` i.e. number of test cases, and then `T` lines will follow each containing a string `S`.

Output Format:
 Print the minimum number of cyclic shifts for each string if it can be made a palindrome, else `-1`.

Constraints:
`1<=T<=100`,
`1<=|S|<=300`, `S` will contains only lower case alphabets `('a'-'z')`.

Sample Input and Output

Input

```
4
abbb
aaabb
aabb
abc
```

Output

```
-1
1
1
-1
```

Explanation: 
For Test Case 2 (`aaabb`): 
 Shift the character at the tail to the head and the result will be "baaab", which is a palindrome. This is an operation which requires minimum number of shifts to make the given string a palindrome.

For Test Case 3 (`aabb`): 
 One way to convert the given string to palindrome is, shift the character at the head to the tail, and the result will be `"abba"`, which is a palindrome. Another way is to shift the character at the tail to the head, and the result will be `"baab"`, which is also a palindrome. Both require only one shift.

```
public class cyclic {

    static boolean flag = false;

    // fn to check if string is palindrome
    static boolean ispal(String s) {
        String reverse = "";
        int length = s.length();
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse = reverse + s.charAt(i);
        reverse = reverse.trim();
        if (s.equals(reverse)) {
            flag = true;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // fn to perform front shift
    static int frontshift(String str) {
        int count = 0;
        String element = "";
        String s1[] = str.split("");
        Deque<String> dequeA = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i < s1.length; i++) {
            dequeA.add(s1[i]);
        }
        while (!ispal(str)) {
            if (count <= str.length()) {
                element = "";
                String firstElement = dequeA.removeFirst();
                dequeA.addLast(firstElement);
                for (String object : dequeA) {
                    element = element + object;
                }
                str = element;
                count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    // fn to perform backshift
    static int backshift(String str) {
        int count = 0;
        String element = "";
        String s1[] = str.split("");
        Deque<String> dequeA = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i < s1.length; i++) {
            dequeA.add(s1[i]);
        }
        while (!ispal(str)) {
            if (count <= str.length()) {
                element = "";
                String firstElement = dequeA.removeLast();
                dequeA.addFirst(firstElement);
                for (String object : dequeA) {
                    element = element + object;
                }
                str = element;
                count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int range = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
            String s = br.readLine();
            int l1 = frontshift(s);
            int l2 = backshift(s);
            if (flag == true) {
                if (l1 <= l2) {
                    list.add(l1);
                } else {
                    list.add(l2);
                }
            } else {
                list.add(-1);
            }
            flag = false;
        }
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your solution?

Comment: @TheLostMind yes I tried and it works for my test cases. Do u hav problem running it ?

Comment: The problem is not knowing that the input was and what the expect output is.

Comment: 2 things I see, 1. Why are you calling reverse.trim()? 2. Why is your index starting at 1 and not 0?

Comment: @PeterLawrey  I'm pretty sure about the expected output. They system checks for some 15 test cases, only for two it is failed. So I guess the input is the problem for me.

Comment: @Codebender Ignore the reverse.trim(); and as I have used split() which doesn't have any regex, 0th index was empty. so I accessed from 1.

Comment: Can you see the output of your program?  How about logging the input?

Comment: @PeterLawrey yup I cans see the output. I can't get you. Enter the integer number(no of strings) followed by the n Strings for which the shift count is to be performed.

Comment: @J.Selva, I don't think the 0th index will be empty in split. Why did you come to such a conclusion?

Comment: The input is the actual text your program reads. What exactly is it?

Comment: @Codebender I did not use java8 while coding this..
Edit: Please see this for better understanding [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718096/why-a-in-the-0th-index-of-an-array-on-perfoaming-a-split-w-o-delimiters)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Program reads the String Again sorry if am wrong.

Comment: What does `br.readLine()` actually read? This is the input to your program.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I will give you sample inputs.
1(number of strings to be entered)
1100(actual string)
Output: 1 (as one shift is required)

Comment: This code is so inefficient it hurts. Why are you building `String`s if you could check it yourself just by comparing characters? Also **if** you build a `String` step by step, use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Fabian Thanks for ur suggestion :)

Comment: @J.Selva, I removed the `1` from the input: seems it's unnecessary. Please check my edit and restore it if I'm wrong.

Comment: @TagirValeev Thank you for the edit. I'm new here and yah it looks perfect now and yes the `1` was not needed. Thanks mate !

Comment: And for the example, `1100` what is the result you are getting?

Comment: @PeterLawrey no `1` is the output as it can be made a palindrome (`0110`) with one back shift. I have edited the question after your questions. is it not clear enough now ?

Comment: I am still waiting to find out which input produces an incorrect result, so someone can reproduce the problem you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved your task not based on your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalyndromeTest {
    static boolean isPalyndrome(String s, int shift) {
        int n = s.length();
        if(shift < 0) shift+=n;
        for(int pos = 0; pos < n/2; pos++) {
            if(s.charAt((pos+shift)%n) != s.charAt((n-pos-1+shift)%n))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static int findShift(String s) {
        for(int shift = 0; shift <= s.length()/2; shift++) {
            if(isPalyndrome(s, shift) || isPalyndrome(s, -shift))
                return shift;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
        for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            System.out.println(findShift(s.nextLine()));
        }
    }
}
```

First, `isPalyndrome` method. It checks whether the string is palyndrome and works with positive or negative shifts as well. Note that, for example, for string of length 5, `shift = -1` is the same as `shift = 4`. We don't create any new strings, we just scan the existing one using the `String.charAt` method. We use `% n` remainder operator to automatically move back to the string beginning when the string end is reached. Note that we should check only the half of the string.

Second, the `findShift` method. It just iterates over all the shifts from `0` to `s.length()/2` (bigger shifts are unnecessary to check as they are equal to the already checked negative shifts). On every iteration it checks both positive and negative shift.

Finally the `main` method which reads the standard input and calls the `findShift` for each input line. It outputs the result immediately, though if you want, you may collect it to the list and output at the end.

Comment: I know my code is not optimal. I have posted this code because for this is what I received "two test cases" failed. I am here to learn how to analyze this code and generate test cases. And yeah your code works fine and it is perfect. Can u figure out the logical mistake if any in posted code.